# ¿Por qué el tamaño de mi CANVAS en PNG convertido por Base64 se reduce?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

estoy creando un método para utilizar la codificación BASE64 de una imagen en otro archivo mediante un POST de un FORM.

Mi problema ocurre cuando recibo la imagen desde el POST en el otro lado del archivo, donde se muestra una reducción significante del tamaño y se puede visualizar que los datos no son los mismos que se muestran antes de enviarlo mediante este método. Adjunto la imagen de como se ve antes y después:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y dejo a continuación el código que he usado del método y el gráfico que se muestra en la anterior imagen:

```
<form id="imagen" action="test2.php" method="POST">
<input id="canvasimg" name="canvasimg" type="text" value=""/>
<button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form> <!-- Aca se realiza el metodo POST para visualizar la imagen en otro sitio -->

<canvas id="canvasid"></canvas> <!-- Aca se forma el gráfico -->


<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("canvasid"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
          data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
      }
    }
}); /* Aca estan las propiedades del gráfico */

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#canvasimg").attr("value", $("#canvasid").get(0).toDataURL("img/png"));
}); /* Este apartado sirve para crear la codificacion BASE64 y pasarla mediante el POST -->

</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Adjunto abajo el código del archivo donde recibe el metodo:

```
<?php $canvasimg = $_POST['canvasimg'];
echo "<img src='$canvasimg'>";
?>
```

Agradezco cualquier apoyo o recomendación, muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Dónde esta el código del otro canvas? Es difícil ayudarte si solo muestras una parte del problema.

Comment: @Mateo Es solo un canvas, el otro gráfico que se muestra es el .png que deriva del metodo POST que se esta enviando del primer archivo.

Comment: @Mateo De igual forma, ya adjunte el código del otro archivo que recibe la codificación de la imagen.

Comment: pareciera que al ser capturada pierde altura la imagen... fijate si tu canvas en el html tiene algun CSS o sus elementos padres que afecten la altura; creo que en tu php ese dato no lo sabe el sistema... entonces `echo "<img src='$canvasimg'>";` le esta haciendo falta el dato/atributo  de la altura

Comment: Tambien pierde altura las letras de la izquierda en general la imagen completa esta perdiendo altura...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Hola, acabo de intentar lo que me recomiendas sobre visualizar la altura del canvas y dentro del código no estoy utiizando ningun CSS, pero si le apliqué un  `<canvas id="canvasid" height="100" width="100"></canvas>`, y de la misma forma le aplique a `<img src='$canvasimg' height="100" width="100">` y no funcionó... creo que el elemento <img> solo esta modificando la altura y el ancho de todo en general mas no de las barras

Comment: se por si las barras nisiqueira son iguales; adicional mira y compara las lineas orizontales ... y donde estan los labels tampoco son iguales es como si tubieras 2 imagenes distintas...

Comment: intenta hacer esto: dale click derecho y luego en descargar imagen y valida si es parecida a lo que envias en formato base64.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si, la he verificado anteriormente y es la misma, pero ya he llegado a la solución del problema, ya publicaré la respuesta en cuestión; Sin antes de agradecerte por hacerme notar las propiedades del gráfico, en resumen, tenia que ver en parte con las opciones del mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ayuda de @ArcanisGK507, me puse a revisar las propiedades del gráfico y me tope con que de por si, la libreria otorga unas propiedades para realizar una animación (de las barras en elevación) comenzando desde abajo y terminando hasta el lugar donde deben llegar por valores determinados dentro del mismo. He removido la animación y removido otra propiedad llamada **bezierCurve**, para evitar que se hagan bordes en este sistema de barras. El código modificado unicamente fue en las opciones del gráfico:

```
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("canvasid"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
          data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      animation: { /* Aca comienza el cambio */
        duration: 0
      },
      bezierCurve: false, /* Aca finaliza */
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
      }
    }
}); /* Aca estan las propiedades del gráfico */
```

Comment: muy bien buena respuesta.